# How to add single property in particular array object using javascript

Tags: javascript

For each skills array object having button.  eg : If I am clicking skill_id En77 how to add the one property(certification_category) for that particular skills array object.

```
{

"_id": "employee_skill_doc",
"_rev": "532-927e8b9f17cfea9642a0380e0fa9a0e3",
"skills": [
   {
       "skill_name": "SDS/2",
       "skill_id": "En77",
       "skill_set_id": "c16",
       "skill_set": "Structural Analysis",
       "skill_sub_ID": "b07",
       "skill_cat_ID": "a01"
   },
   {
       "skill_name": "Adobe Flash Catalyst",
       "skill_id": "Te369",
       "skill_set_id": "c90",
       "skill_set": "Prototyping Tools",
       "skill_sub_ID": "b26",
       "skill_cat_ID": "a03"

   } 

])
```

Here, mentioned expected output

```
{

"_id": "employee_skill_doc",
"_rev": "532-927e8b9f17cfea9642a0380e0fa9a0e3",
"skills": [
   {
       "skill_name": "SDS/2",
       "skill_id": "En77",
       "skill_set_id": "c16",
       "skill_set": "Structural Analysis",
       "skill_sub_ID": "b07",
       "skill_cat_ID": "a01",
       “certification_category”:”1”
   },

   {
       "skill_name": "Adobe Flash Catalyst",
       "skill_id": "Te369",
       "skill_set_id": "c90",
       "skill_set": "Prototyping Tools",
       "skill_sub_ID": "b26",
       "skill_cat_ID": "a03"

   }]
}
```

Comment: You can use obj.prop = 'value' ....

Comment: why are the downvotes for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want. Bad practice to use underscore notation. No need to enclose object keys in quotes.

```
var length = objName.skills.length, 
    i;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (objName.skills[i].skill_id === 'En77') {
        objName.skills[i].certification_category = '1';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below loop will find the skill with the given `skill_id` and then you can add whatever you want to it.

```
for(i = 0; i<blah.skills.length; i++){

    var skill = blah.skills[i];

    if(skill.skill_id == "En77"){

        skill.certification_category = "1";
        /// add whatever you want
        break;
    }

}
```